# How do I create a user in the firebase emulator via cloud function?

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

When trying to create a user programmatically via a cloud function while using the emulators, I consistently get an error about credential implementation. I am failing to see any credential issues since it's the admin SDK in an emulator environment.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp({projectId: 'mytestapp' } );

exports.createuser = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    admin.auth().createUser({
        email: request.query.email,
        emailVerified: false,
        password: request.query.password,
        disabled: false,
    })
        .then((userRecord) => {
            // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
            response.json({ success: userRecord })
            return null
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            response.json({ error: error })       
        });
})
```

And the error I get is this:

> {"error":{"code":"app/invalid-credential","message":"Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Error fetching access token: Error while parsing response data: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0". Raw server response: "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://dnserrorassist.att.net/search/?q=http://metadata.google.internal%2FcomputeMetadata%2Fv1%2Finstance%2Fservice-accounts%2Fdefault%2Ftoken%26akaCid%3Daaaaaaaa%26t%3D0%26bc%3D"/><script type="text/javascript">window.location="http://dnserrorassist.att.net/search/?q="+escape(window.location)+"&r="+escape(document.referrer)+"&t=0&akaCid=aaaaaaaa&bc=";". Status code: "200". Outgoing request: "GET [http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token.\"\"."}}](http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token.%5C%22%5C%22.%22%7D%7D)

My understanding is that when using the emulator, authentication is included.

As a note, I am calling the function from:

```
localhost:5001/newproject-1b38d/us-central1/createuser?email=Jared@test.com&password=123456
```

When I add a document using the code from the firestore documentation, I get no errors. Only when trying to create a Firebase authentication user.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further research/reading (and updating to the most recent versions of firebase/firestore) and still being unsuccesssful, I was able to identify the need to set the application credentials vial the cli done so like this.

- I download the service account file from the firestore console.
- Then direct my cli to that file with this small code snippet:

  export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="Users/Jared/Downloads/newproject-1b38d-firebase-adminsdk-k9lmw-8070573114.json"

This gives me the following success message:

```
{"success":{"uid":"6yaEOww1PSU1G5smimLo7qMCfty2","email":"jaredgibb@gmail.com","emailVerified":false,"disabled":false,"metadata":{"lastSignInTime":null,"creationTime":"Sun, 29 Aug 2021 15:48:26 GMT"},"tokensValidAfterTime":"Sun, 29 Aug 2021 15:48:26 GMT","providerData":[]}}
```

**[Update]**

Weirdly, the users were created in the live backend. Not the emulator. But the errors went away. Only now I have a bunch of users I’ll need to delete.